# Android, change fragment textview from activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've one activity with 3 fragments,
- top fragment has a textview,
- center fragment has main content
- bottom fragment has a tabwidget

at the start I want my top fragment to display a "text", but when I click on a tab and the center fragment shows me another fragment (this is working fine), I want to display another text in my top fragment.

how can I do this?

thanks,
Pedro Simão

Comment: Show the code, please.

Comment: what code do you want ?

Comment: That code which produce problems and you can't get solution for it.

Comment: If you are able to click a tab in your bottom Fragment and it changes your centre Fragment, what is so difficult about it also changing the text in the top Fragment?

Comment: I don't know.. i try to get the view of the top fragment and change the text but the application launch fail.

Comment: Show your code. All you need to do is create a public method in your top Fragment code and have the Activity call it. The top Fragment can then change its own text.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to each Fragment in your Activity. Then, add a method to the top Fragment to change the text. Then, call that method from your Activity.